# ANSI colour codes don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ansi-escape

I'm trying to use ANSI colour codes to output coloured text in python, but this is what happens:

```
print("\033[1;32;40mBright Green")
```

Outputted: [1;32;40mBright Green

I am running python 3.5.2 on macOS Sierra. Is my code missing something, or can I not use this on a mac?

Comment: have you tried colorama?

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you running your code in a script from a shell, or are you running within an IDE?

Comment: @Blckknght I'm running within an IDE, IDLE to be precise.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I've tried various modules, but my computer doesn't seem to recognise them - I'm told 'no such module'

Comment: do you have more than one version of python installed?

Comment: IDLE's terminal emulator is pretty basic, I doubt it makes any attempt to handle ANSI colors. Try running Python from shell in a terminal emulator and I suspect it will work.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint no, I don't think so